# Replicating the weighted averages from polljunkie poll

Tags: csv, excel-formula, weighted-average

How can I replicate the Result of the poll from the CSV of the polljunkie poll?

example poll: [Result](http://www.polljunkie.com/poll/dnrxbf/example/view)

example CSV: [CSV](http://www.polljunkie.com/poll/dnrxbf/example/Export)

I've split the individual results from the single cell and numbered A-E as 1-5. Then I multiplied every position with its weight (also 1-5) & devided that by its sum, but this does not result in the same "ranking" as the poll result.

Can you give me a formula to replicate the polljunkie result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to get the sum of the position and then divide by the number of responses.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((FIND(E2,SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$5,",",""))))/4
```

[image]

Comment: @wouter215 If this answers your question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.